# Help me understand constant elimination semantically

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

Notational convention: $\mathcal{L}c$ denotes an expansion of $\mathcal{L}$ by a constant symbol $c$, $\tfrac{z}{c}$ denotes the substitution of a constant symbol $c$ with a variable $z$.

I know that

$$
X \vdash_{\mathcal{L}c} \alpha \Rightarrow X \tfrac{z}{c} \vdash_{\mathcal{L}} \alpha \tfrac{z}{c}
$$

for "almost all" (we can see which ones are applicable from how the proof of this statement is carried out) variables $z$.

I read somewhere in the book that the satisfiability relation $\models$ is the same for all first-order languages $\mathcal{L}$. Coupling this with completeness and soundness of FOL (i.e. $\vdash \,\, \Leftrightarrow \,\, \models$), I derived

$$
X \vDash \alpha \Rightarrow X \tfrac{z}{c} \vDash \alpha \tfrac{z}{c}
$$

from the above statement. Note that my main mistake could be somewhere in this inference, as I admit that I didn't go into the details of it and I also don't completely trust my memory that the author said $\models \,\, = \,\, \models_{\mathcal{L}}$ for all $\mathcal{L}$.

I tried to prove $X \vDash \alpha \Rightarrow X \tfrac{z}{c} \vDash \alpha \tfrac{z}{c}$ because I wanted to understand constant elimination semantically, but failed. Please, help me understand the semantic intuition behind this concept.

Comment: The issue is: what does it mean that $X(z) \vDash \alpha (z)$? where with an abuse of notation with $X(z)$ I mean that var $z$ occurs free in the set of premises? The specifications for $\vDash$ does not consider the $z$ as universally quantified in the formulas (e.g. $\forall z \alpha(z)$) but as "constant" across the $\vDash$ relation, i.e. like: "for every $z$: $X \vDash \alpha$". This amounts to consider it like a "constant" in the context of the proof. Conclusion:if we have $X(c) \vDash \alpha(c)$ we can replace the constant $c$ with a free var **everywhere** and the relation still hold.

Comment: What I mean with "z is a "constant" across the ⊨ relation"? The semantical clause says: for an interpretation $\mathcal I$ and for a var assignment $v$ to the free var $z$ such that $X$ is satisfied by $v$ in $\mathcal I$, also $\alpha$ is satisfied. The variable assignment assigns to $z$ a value that is "constant" across the proof.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thank you for your engagement. I don't yet have a resolution to my problem, but I have discovered some flaws in my initial post. For example, the relation $\models$ is *not* the same across all languages. Each language $\mathcal{L}$ has its own satisfiability relation $\models_{\mathcal{L}}$. We can forget the indices of satisfiability relations *only* in special cases. I guess I will work on from here ...

Comment: IMO, that is irrelevant... :-) The $\vDash$ relation is "indexed" to a language simply because it is formalized in terms of models, and models are based on interpretation that are specific for a language: if the language has a constant $c$, the interpretation must define a meaning for that constant. Fullstop. Both the premises and the conclusion of the argument must be in the same language.

Answer (score 1):

The basic intuition behind the semantic claim is simply that logical consequence is preserved under the elimination of constants. More specifically, the logical information a constant carries in a model can always be carried as well by a variable in model for a language without that constant. This is possible, because we can always expand languages and models. The following proof sketch shows how expansions come into play here.

Let $\mathcal{M}$ be an $\mathcal{L}$-structure and $\beta$ be an assignment with $\mathcal{M}, \beta \models X \frac{z}{c}$. Let $\mathcal M'$ be the $\mathcal{Lc}$-expansion of $\mathcal{M}$ such that $c^{\mathcal{M'}} = \beta(z)$. According to the coincidence property we have that $\mathcal{M'}, \beta \models X \frac{z}{c}$. Since $\mathcal{M'}, \beta \frac{\beta(z)}{z} \models X \frac{z}{c}$ it follows that $\mathcal{M'}, \beta \frac{c^{\mathcal{M'}}}{z} \models X\frac{z}{c}$. So, by the substitution lemma we get $\mathcal{M'}, \beta \models (X\frac{z}{c})\frac{c}{z} = X$. Consequently, $\mathcal{M'}, \beta \models \alpha = (\alpha\frac{z}{c})\frac{c}{z}$, which, again using the substitution lemma and the coincidence property, implies $\mathcal{M}, \beta \models \alpha\frac{z}{c}$.